# change width of image on toggle

Tags: jquery

I need to change the width of an image with in a toggled div.  The problem is that I have multiple toggles on the page and that all the image width's change when I click on the toggle link and not just the on one within the div that I want

```
$('.toggle').click(function() {
 $(this).prev('.guidebox').slideToggle(400);
 $('.toggle').toggleClass("active")

 if ($(this).html() === 'less') {
        $(this).html('more');
        $('.guideImage img').animate({
            width: '187px',
            height: '124px'
          }, 50, function() {
          });


    } else {
        $(this).html('less');

        $('.guideImage img').animate({
        width: '300px',
        height: '124px'
      }, 50, function() {
      });
    }

return false;

  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.guideImage img', this).animate({
```

Possibly?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without all the code, but I think this might work.

Change

`$('.guideImage img').animate(`

to

`$(this).prev('.guidebox').find('.guideImage img').animate(`

Comment: thanks.  I had to use .parent instead as it was outside but now working :)